# Checked changing opacity of another element using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make images' (on my webpage) opacity change when different accordions are expanded (input:checked).

This is the site in question: http://oasisexpressautowash.com/packages

You'll see that the "your vehicle is receiving: package menu" on the left lights up whichever package your hovering on. I am trying to make the lights come on when their matching accordion tab gets expanded.

This is the js (hoverfunctions.js) I'm tinkering with to achieve the desired effect.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery("ul.container input#ac-1").click(function() {
    $('img.top').css({
      opacity: 1.0
    });
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#mpactivator img.top').css({
        opacity: 0
      });
    } else {
      $('img.top').css({
        opacity: 1.0
      });
    }
  });

  jQuery("ul.container input#ac-2").click(function() {
    $('img.top').css({
      opacity: 1.0
    });
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#lavaactivator img.top').css({
        opacity: 0
      });
      $('#rainxactivator img.top').css({
        opacity: 0
      });
      $('#packageactivator img.top').css({
        opacity: 0
      });
      $('#tireshineactivator img.top').css({
        opacity: 0
      });
      $('#bpactivator img.top').css({
        opacity: 0
      });
    } else {
      $('img.top').css({
        opacity: 1.0
      });
    }
  });

  jQuery("ul.container input#ac-3").click(function() {
    $('img.top').css({
      opacity: 1.0
    });
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#hotwaxactivator img.top').css({
        opacity: 0
      });
      $('#rainxactivator img.top').css({
        opacity: 0
      });
      $('#packageactivator img.top').css({
        opacity: 0
      });
      $('#tireshineactivator img.top').css({
        opacity: 0
      });
      $('#bpactivator img.top').css({
        opacity: 0
      });
    } else {
      $('img.top').css({
        opacity: 1.0
      });
    }
  });

  jQuery("ul.container input#ac-4").click(function() {
    $('img.top').css({
      opacity: 1.0
    });
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#rainxactivator img.top').css({
        opacity: 0
      });
      $('#packageactivator img.top').css({
        opacity: 0
      });
      $('#tireshineactivator img.top').css({
        opacity: 0
      });
    } else {
      $('img.top').css({
        opacity: 1.0
      });
    }
  });
  jQuery("ul.container input#ac-5").click(function() {
    $('img.top').css({
      opacity: 1.0
    });
  });

});
```

Now i'm trying to retain css functionality of packages you're receiving menu after JS is executed as well as get the opacity to return to its former value when another input is checked.

Now, when you hover over the buttons after expanding an accordion, they don't light up.
And after you expand another accordion the lights from the previous expanded accordion remain lit.

Please help!

Comment: better add same class to the respective accordion and the left items and get the event based on class clicked or hovered.

Comment: I think you'd better use `$(element).on("click", function(){})` and `$(this).is(":checked")` to listen to the `input` state change, instead of `.checked()`, that I'm not sure  it exists.

Comment: @suchit That doesn't sound like a bad idea. I think i might give that a try. It sounds much simpler.

Comment: @BeNdErR Yea i knew it didn't exist because console flags it; I was just trying to get what i was going for across

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery().checked()` is not a valid event handler. You should use the `jQuery.click()` or `jQuery.change()` event instead.

Inside the change event, you should check if the element is checked and then take appropriate action.

```
jQuery(".chbd-ac-container input:nth-child(1)").click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('img.top').css({
            opacity: 0
        });
    } else {
        $('img.top').css({
            opacity: 1.0
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Dear Dev-an, goodmorning. thanks for your help couple days ago. So i changed my accordion and the image opacity changing when checked function you supplied works exceptionally. There's only a couple of problems i'm running into. When another <input> is selected, the lights remain on from the other packages. the other problem is that once the script gets executed (ie: when a portfolio gets expanded) the css:hover functionality of the "package you're receiving menu" is terminated. I remember reading up somewhere on stackoverflow a problem similar to mine. Help? just one last time?:)

Comment: For your first problem, you should add the following in the beginning of your client event handler functions: jQuery('img.top').css({opacity: 1.0}); This will turn off all lights, before specific lights for the given package are turned on by your event.

Comment: Regarding your second problem, I assume you are talking about the hover functionality on the package lights. If that's the case, the hover functionality is working correctly. The problem is hover is meant to turn the light on, but if the light is already on because of some package <input> selected, so you see no change. You should use hover on an opaque light and you'll see that hover indeed works fine.

Comment: Aw how simple. I wish I could have picked up on that on my own. Yes the hover functionality was working correctly exactly how you put it; my mistake for even posting that it wasn't, however, now that i added that line of script to the beginning of my client event handler functions, hover functionality is now not working whenever an <input> is selected. (it's like i predicted that this problem would occur xD lol)